# Circle CI with yarn.lock instead of package.lock

Tags: yarnpkg, circleci

The error i get is

```
error computing cache key: template: cacheKey:1:30: executing "cacheKey" at <checksum "~/project/package-lock.json">: error calling checksum: open /home/circleci/project/package-lock.json: no such file or directory
```

and my config.yaml file is

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@3.0.0
workflows:
  node-tests:
    jobs:
      - node/test
```

How do I tell CircleCI to use the yarn.lock file?

Comment: If you want to use the orb, see https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/node. Or do it more manually per https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/yarn/.

Answer (score 1):

If defining your own jobs, ou can change the cache key in your job's steps to use `yarn.lock`. Example from the [docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/yarn/):

```
      - restore_cache:
          name: Restore Yarn Package Cache
          keys:
            - yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: yarn install --immutable
      - save_cache:
          name: Save Yarn Package Cache
          key: yarn-packages-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
          paths:
            - ~/.cache/yarn
```

Comment: Where does the above code snippet go in the yaml file, under orbs or workflows or jobs? Complete newb I'm sorry!

Comment: Note this is the manual version *not* the orb.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Looking at the Orb docs, I didn't see a way to change the cache key without actually defining a job.

Comment: @Bill steps go in jobs, jobs go in workflows, and orbs are just predefined bits of config. This config change would go in a job you'd define to replace the default `node/test` (see [this bit of YAML](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/node#usage-run_tests_with_yarn)).

Comment: So do I remove orbs: and add the snippet under jobs: ??

Comment: I'd expect `pkg-manager: yarn` (see docs I linked above) to update the caching appropriately, but I haven't actually tried it out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, you're right. I was looking for that in the orb source and didn't see it, but I was in the wrong dropdown.

Comment: @Bill see what jonrsharpe said: no need to define your own jobs/steps manually, setting `pkg-manager: yarn` should do the trick.

Comment: `pkg-manager: yarn` sounds great but do I replace the orb with it, or does it go under jobs or workflows? Could you update the code snippet above fo me?